# Webaudio sound stops on Chrome for Android after about 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, web-audio-api

I'm running into an issue with WebAudio on Chrome for Android.

I'm experiencing this on a Samsung Galaxy S3 (GT-I9300) with:

- Chrome version 44.0.2403.133
- Android 4.3.0

Here is the code I'm using to try and isolate the issue:

```
var audioContext;
if(window.AudioContext) {
    audioContext = new AudioContext();
}

var startTime = Date.now();
var lastTrigger;

var gain = audioContext.createGain();
gain.gain.value = 1;
gain.connect(audioContext.destination);

var buttonTrigger = document.getElementById('trigger');
buttonTrigger.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    var oscillator =  audioContext.createOscillator();
    oscillator.type = "square";
    oscillator.frequency.value = 100 +  (Math.cos(audioContext.currentTime)*100);
    oscillator.connect(gain);
    oscillator.start(0);
    oscillator.stop(audioContext.currentTime+0.1);

    lastTrigger = Date.now();
});

var timer = document.getElementById('timer');
setInterval(function() {
    if(lastTrigger) { timer.textContent = Date.now() - lastTrigger; }
}, 1000);
```

And here it is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vzze21L/1/)

This simply creates an oscillator node and plays on clicking a button. On my phone, if I do not click the button for about a minute and a half or two minutes, I no longer get any sound.

There are no errors thrown.

Does anyone have any experience of this issue and a possible workaround?

This issue originally appeared in a much larger app using Phaser to play sounds from a m4a file, so this is not solely to do with the oscillator.

**UPDATE**

According to the [Chromium bug ticket](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=518863) this issue has now been fixed.

Comment: As an aside, `gain.value = 1` should be `gain.gain.value = 1`. It doesn't make a difference in this example because the default gain is `1`, but it would matter if you wanted to change the gain. See the [GainNode documentation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GainNode) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've edited the original post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After experiencing the same problem on Android. I found a better solution than playing a "dummy sound" every 30sec.

Just remember the time when you last played over your context:

```
var lastPlayed = new Date().getTime();
var audioSource = context.createBufferSource();
    audioSource.connect( context.destination );
    audioSource.buffer = sb;
    audioSource.start( 0 );
```

The next time you play a sample/sound Just check the time passed and reset the AudioContext

```
if(new Date().getTime()-lastPlayed>30000){   // Time passed since last playing is greater than 30 secs
     context.close();
     context=new AudioContext();
}
```

For Android this works like charm.

Comment: You can also detect this situation by checking if the audioContext .currentTime is not progressing despite `.state === "running"`. Then you don't have to hardcode the 30 seconds and I actually find the time variable, sometimes it seems to take 2 minutes to trigger broken audiocontext.

Comment: Hi. I have a theory. If you create the context a second time, the second context will never trigger the bug. Can anyone confirm this ?? If it is true, you could simply create a context, close it, and create a second one .. and all should be ok.

Comment: Forget my theory, it is not true. The context can freeze any time.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you're seeing is an auto-shutdown of Web Audio when there's no sound for a while.  What happens if you click the button a second time, a second or so after the first?  (Web Audio can take some time (order of tens of milliseconds, at least) to restart.)

The suspend()/resume() methods, and looking at the context.state, would be helpful here.

Comment: And here is a related Chrome bug:  https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=518863

Comment: @cwilso It doesn't resume until I reload the page and, forgot to mention in my post, context.state was still 'running' when I checked it.

Comment: It looks like the bug report @RaymondToy posted is precisely what I was looking for. I searched chromium bugs and found a few similar things but not that issue.

Comment: Still looking for a workaround. I tried playing a silent track every 20 seconds but that didn't stop the issue. If I play an oscillator node every so often it works but can't really do that in the game I'm working on.

Comment: I think your silent track should not truly be silent.  A very low level noise might be enough to keep things alive.

Comment: @RaymondToy Yes, a not really silent 'silent track' would fix the issue. For me, playing some incidental or atmospheric sounds worked better but both  fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@RaymondToy's comment answers this question. There is a bug with Chrome on Android (at least for Samsung Galaxy S3/4). Webaudio stops playing sounds after a period of inactivity. Where inactivity is essentially silence.

The only work around I can find is to play some kind of sound at intervals. I have experimented with playing a sound every 30 seconds and that stopped the problem.

I also tried playing some kind of silent noise (silent audio buffer or silent part of an m4a audio file or muted sound), neither of which solved the problem.